# Подписка на событие для локальной переменной - кнопки

Tags: winforms, vb.net

У меня такая проблема, сам пишу на на с#, но понадобилось конвертировать код на VB.net.
**Описание:**

Хочу создать кнопку с обработчиком события, но нужен оператор WithEvents. 
Как мне подправить код, что бы для локальной переменной работало событие?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
        Dim Button1 As New Button 
        Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(109, 41)                                  
        Button1.Name = "Button1" 
        Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)      
        Button1.TabIndex = 0
        Button1.Text = "Button1" 
        Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Button1_Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("test")
    End Sub 

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Handles`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/handles-clause) нужен для подписки на события, определенные на уровне модуля/класса.

Для подписки на событие во время исполнения [`AddHandler`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement) необходим и достаточен, `Handles` можно убрать:

```
AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Button1_Click
...    
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("test")
End Sub
```